# Why a white-space is occuring before a direct child in li tag if I use list-style:inside decimal?

Tags: html, css

This is my following CSS piece of code

```css
  ol{
      padding-left:0;
      list-style: inside decimal;
    }
    ol li :first-child{
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
    <ol>
        <li>
            <p>Item 1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            Item 2
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Whenever HTML is rendered into a browser there is a white-space being added, Any specific reason for that?

[image]

Comment: yes because you are using <p> tag inside first <li>.In second one you just passing text to the <li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of getting around this problem:

Use Flexbox to create the horizontal list of items instead of trying an inline-block solution. This handles everything for you, and is definitely the preferred solution:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

If you need to rely on inline-block, you could set the font-size of the list to 0. This only works if your blocks are not sized with ems (based on the font-size, so the block size would also end up being 0). rems would be a good choice here:

```
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  ...
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  ...
}
```

Or you could set negative margin on the list items:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: -0.25rem;
}
```

You can also solve this problem by putting your list items all on the same line in the source, which causes the whitespace nodes to not be created in the first place:

```
<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
```

Credits :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Answer (score 0):

**`display:inline` is not apply to `p` tag**

```css
ol{
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: inside decimal;
}

ol li:first-child{
 
  display: inline;
  background: red;
}

ol li:first-child > p {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item 2
    </li>
</ol>
```

use `display:inline` to `p` tag also..

```css
ol{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style: inside decimal;
}
ol li :first-child{
  display: inline;
  background: red;
}

ol li:first-child > p{
  display: inline;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item 2
    </li>
</ol>
```

also you can add below code for removing default margin & padding for all `html tag` ...

```
*,*::after, *::before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: still whitespace renders in DOM :)

Comment: `display:inline` will not give you extra space.. also your code is working fine in the snippet..  i think there are others problem with your code..

Comment: @Temani Afif  i think no.. please review my answer..

Comment: @Temani Afif  see his posted  picture....when he will define `ol li:first-child > p` to background color ..see what happening ..

Comment: @Temani Afif he also share prices of code. not full example.. maybe there is a lot of solution .. i did not see anything wrong with my answer..

Comment: not sure what you are trying to explain to me. I simply said that his code is already applying display:inline (this is a fact, that's all). I never said you are wrong or your answer is wrong or there is any issue with your answer.

Comment: would you describe what is happening with my first example...